# C# 2 forms and opacity question

Tags: c#, winforms, opacity

I have 2 forms. on the second form i have a track bar. Whenever that track bar changes it's value, I want form 1 to become transparent. My code.

opacitytrackBar1.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(opacitytrackBar1_ValueChanged);

but what is the code for setting form1's opacity?
thanks!

Comment: It may be helpful to know what UI framework you're using, e.g. WinForms, WPF, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you after the `.Opacity` property on the form object?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Yes I am trying to use the .opacity property. I tried the link that you provided, but I get the following error:

Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Opacity.get'

Comment: You need to use it on your instance of form1. In your event handler use `this.Opacity`

Comment: You may not be understanding me. I have a track bar on form2, I want form 1 to be at an opacity according to form2's trackbar.

Comment: Do you have any relationship between form1 and form2? Is form2 opened as a child of form1? You need a reference between them so that you can get a hold of your instance of form1 and use it there

Comment: Um by child you mean if form 2 is opened by a command in form 1? if so, then no. form 2 is just always there.

Comment: By child I meant displayed using something like `form2Instance.Show(form1Instance)`, if it is you can use this.Parent from the instance of form2 if not you'll need some way to get a hold of form1 from form2. Possibly creating a property on form2 to hold a reference to form1

Answer (score 1):

Check this sites:

[Fading Windows Form in C#](http://www.vcskicks.com/windows_form_fade.php)

[Transparency Tutorial with C# - Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/CsTranspTutorial3.aspx)

[Transparent forms (form opacity)](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial105_Transparent-forms-%28form-opacity%29.html)

Regards

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Opacity.set': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

Comment: this.Opacity=0.5;
MessageBox.Show("Back to normal opacity");
this.Opacity=1.0; Check this.

Comment: I want form 2 to control form1's opacity. Form 2 is the one with the trackbar. if I use this.opacity, form 2 becomes transparent. I want form 1 to be.